# How to handle errors between 400 and 499 (And if possible, also between 500 and 599 to handle server errors)

Tags: python, flask

So I am making a website and would like to handle all errors for the client and server side.

I tried looking at the solution from [How can I implement a custom error handler for all HTTP errors in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760113/how-can-i-implement-a-custom-error-handler-for-all-http-errors-in-flask)

I changed it to my needs

```
@app.errorhandler(range(400, 499))
```

then got an output that said that it had to be a class..

Then I remember that it's not a if statement!

I am currently left with this:

```
@app.errorhandler(range(400, 599))
def uhoh(error):
return returnerr("Sorry, we encountered an error.. Us robots don't know what this means: " + error + ".. Sorry :/", error.code)
```

My returnerr function:

```
def returnerr(msg, code):
return render_template("error.html", msg=msg, code=code)
```

Any solutions?
P.S.
I can't do a for loop, as I am unsure how to except all general http errors..
I am also new to flask
Thanks :)

Comment: Currently trying out ```@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def all_exception_handler(error):
   return 'Error', 500```

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have made an question before I did some more research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a way..

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def all_exception_handler(error):

return "Error: " + error.code
```

Thanks to [How to intercept all exceptions in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258159/how-to-intercept-all-exceptions-in-flask)